# Unit Circles in $\mathbb{R} ^2$

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, circles

So I am asked to plot, for a given $p$, the $unit\space  circles\space  in \space \mathbb{R} ^2$. (No further information has been provided about $p$.

So what I understand is that an $unit \space circle$ is a circle with a radius of 1. So what does it mean to plot $unit\space  circles\space  in \space \mathbb{R} ^2$? I emphasize the word *circles*.

What am I missing?

Here it is, word to word, because obviously, it is quite ambiguous.

[image]

Comment: All the unit circles through p...but it very ambiguous. It should be a bundle of circles

Comment: @MattG88 But can you explain more about what unit *circles* in $\mathbb{R} ^2$ mean? The question is really ambiguous!

Comment: A typo?  Or an instructor with poor grasp of english?  Also of question is *what* about p?  Is p a point on the circle? the center of the circle or something else.  If p is the center there is one unit circle with center p and radius 1.  If p is one point of the circle, there are an infinite number of unit circles containing the point (example if the point is (0,1) the unit circles centered at (0,0) (0,2),(1,1) , ($\sqrt 2$, 1- $\sqrt 2$) or any other).  To "plot" *all* of them would be to result in a big black solid circle of radius two.

Comment: Could you type out the excercise word for word, letter for letter, *exactly* as written.  Becuase, yes, it is *very* ambiguous

Comment: @fleablood I will do it now

Comment: @fleablood added word to word version!

Comment: *If* is means all the unit circles that contain point p = (a,b) then that will be all the points {(x,y) so that (x-c)^2 + (y-d)^2 = 1 and (c-a)^2 + (d-b)^2 = 1} which will .... well, after a lot of work will turn out to be all {(x,y) so the (x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 <= 4}.

Comment: Okay, that just means for all the point**s** that are inputted for each point the output will be **a** circle, so you are to write a function that will input point**s** and ouput circle**s**.  For p there will be *one* circle.  For q there will be one *different* circle.  That's all.

Comment: @fleablood can you write this as answe so that I can mark it?